# Sorting complex object issue

Tags: mongodb

I need to sort my collection that way:

```
db.collection.find().sort({'stp.KEY1':1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5241eb2ed8b991543d931eee"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY2" : 5 },  {  "KEY1" : 500 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("521ef6e6d7b99105020cb0b9"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY2" : 5 },  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("522dd25fd8b9912822498a62"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY3" : 1000 },  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5243fb6ed8b991641ef6a5b9"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 300 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5243fbb2d8b991651ea98477"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 500 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5245611bd7b991d87cb3ec3c"), "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }
```

Does somebody has a secret sauce to do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: That's weird, that should work and if I reverse the sort using `{'stp.KEY1': -1}` instead that _does_ work.

Comment: Do you realy it works descending and not ascending ?

Comment: Now I remember why it's behaving this way: when you sort ascending by a field in an array, the docs are sorted using the minimum value of each doc's elements.  So because the first element in the first three docs doesn't have `KEY1` fields, those are first.  When you sort descending it takes the max value of all elements so the elements where its missing don't affect it.

Comment: from my point of vue it's a bug.

Comment: but your desired result is not sorted by any key if you want to sort by KEY1 then your result should be 
    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 300 } ] }`

    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 500 } ] }`

    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY2" : 5 },  {  "KEY1" : 500 } ] }`

    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }`

    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY2" : 5 },  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }`

    `{ "stp" : [  {  "KEY3" : 1000 },  {  "KEY1" : 1000 } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not sort your collection by a subdocument key. When issue your command: `db.collection.find().sort({'stp.KEY1':1})` it sorts it only on `stp` key which is not what you want.

So you have just few options right now

1. Sort this in your application layer. To do this, you need to return your document and then to sort it with whatever programming language you are using.
2. But if you always want your results to be sorted, you can achieve this by using $sort in your $push operator. In your case you would do something like this:

.

```
db.coll.update(
  { _id : ID },
  { 
     $push: {
       stp: {
          $each: [{ KEY1: 999}],
          $sort: { KEY1: 1 }
       }
     }
  })
```

This way after any update your subdocument will be sorted. And then if you retrieve it you will not need to sort it.